# builder.build().getShardManager() returns null (JDA Discord Bot) | how do I call the shardmanager?

Tags: java, null, sharding, discord-jda

I am new to JDA discord bot and encountered a problem with the **builder.build().getShardManager()** method.
At some points in my code I need the s**hardManager** but I dont know how to get it.
I found out that getShardManager() can be called on an **JDA object** (here: JDABuilder.build())
but it only returns a null reference. (The main class crashes at line 4 with a **nullpointerexception**)
(without the shardmanager the bot works)

How do I obtain the **shardmanager** correctly?

### The main code

```
this.builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN);
builder.addEventListeners(new CommandHandler());
shardManager = this.builder.build().getShardManager();
shardManager.setActivity(Activity.playing("Do smth."));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [JDA](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html) Object and not the [ShardManager](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/sharding/ShardManager.html).

try something like this:

```
this.builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN);
builder.addEventListeners(new CommandHandler());
JDA jda = this.builder.build();
jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing("Hello World!"));
```

You can also set the [Activity](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Activity.html) before building the Bot

```
this.builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN);
builder.addEventListeners(new CommandHandler());
builder.setActivity(Activity.playing("Hello World!"));
JDA jda = this.builder.build();
```

Comment: Ah I understand thank you. seems like they put the methods that used to be on the shardManager on the JDA.

Comment: No, you just didn't build a shard manager. The readme explains this [here](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#example-sharding---using-defaultshardmanager)